# Performance and multithreading on iPad vs iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, performance, ipad

I have an iPad/iPhone universal app that spins off a lot of tasks using GCD.  I've found that the performance on iPhone 4 is substantially worse than on iPad 1.  Everything works well on iPad 1, with tasks being performed in the background without slowing the user interface.  But on iPhone 4, tasks seem to not be performed smoothly on the background and it is slowing down my UI.

I've been testing on iPad 1 with the philosophy that if the iPad 1 can do it quickly, any device can do it quickly (excluding 3GS, which is the slowest device I support, but I don't care about it too much), but actually in trying to solve my problem I found that [iPhone 4 is actually a little slower than iPad 1](http://www.iphonebenchmark.net/cpumark_chart.html).  However, the performance of my app on iPhone 4 is substantially worse (say by a factor of 3-4), which is not in line with the reported processor speeds of the devices.

So my question is: Does iPhone 4 handle multithreading differently than iPad 1 in a way that could affect performance?  And if so, is there a technique to get around this?

I'm running iOS 5.1.1 on the iPad and 6.1.3 on the iPhone 4.

Comment: What versions of iOS are on the two devices? Have you used Instruments to see what is going on?

Comment: See edit for iOS versions.  What should I look for in instruments?

Comment: I have a lot of concurrent stuff going on, too, and haven't seen anything of this order of magnitude. The WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=235), covers diverse topics (many of which are unlikely to be relevant here), but does have a few illustrations of using Instruments to identify issues (e.g. use of CPU strategy, use of System Trace and "Record Waiting Threads" to identify contention issues, etc.).